# Como pasar los datos ingresados de una estructura a mayuscula

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

Quiero que los datos que ingreso de la estrutura "Libros" se pasen directamente a mayuscula. Se que hay que usar la funcion toupper() pero no se como aplicarlo cuando trabajo con estructuras.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>


//Estructura del libro.
typedef struct{
    char titulo[100];
    char genero[100];
    int paginas;
    int anio_de_edicion;
    char numero_isbn[100];
    char editorial[100];
}Libros;

//Funcion para datos del libros.
void alta(Libros * libros){
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Titulo: ");
    gets(libros->titulo);
    printf("genero: ");
    gets(libros->genero);
    printf("paginas: ");
    scanf("%d", &libros->paginas);
    printf("año de edicion: ");
    scanf("%d", &libros->anio_de_edicion);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("numero isbn: ");
    gets(libros->numero_isbn);
    printf("editorial: ");
    gets(libros->editorial);
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo optaría por crear primeramente una función que permitiese convertir una cadena cualquiera a mayúsculas, como por ejemplo:

```
#include <ctype.h>

void aMayusculas(char* ptr)
{
  for( ; *ptr, ++ptr )
    *ptr = toupper(*ptr);
}
```

El segundo paso sería adaptar el código de lectura para realizar las conversiones una a una:

```
void alta(Libros * libros){
  // ...

  aMayusculas(libros->titulo);
  aMayusculas(libros->genero);
  aMayusculas(libros->numero_isbn);
  aMayusculas(libros->editorial_isbn);
}
```

Como nota adicional, `fflush` está diseñado para ser usado **única** y **exclusivamente** con salidas. `fflush(stdin)` no está soportado por el estándar, luego es probable que con otros compiladores el resultado no sea el que tu esperas. Yo en tu lugar evitaría ese uso de `fflush`.

Comment: El utiliza struct con char[] de tamaño fijo, que **no tienen porque terminar en un \0**. Esto es un despiste por tu parte, seguro ;-) Edita la respuesta y tienes mi voto.

Comment: @Trauma La respuesta está dada en base al código que ha puesto y `fgets` *sí* finaliza las cadenas con `\0`. Bueno, realmente no sería únicamente `fgets` sino la inmensa mayoría de las funciones de entrada/salida que trabajan con `char*`. De hecho si no terminasen en `\0` no podría hacer posteriormente `printf("%s",libros->titulo)`, como asumo que está haciendo. Tendría que hacer uso de artificios los cuales al menos yo pongo la mano en el fuego no está utilizando.

Comment: @Trauma Por supuesto que se podría hacer una versión tal que `void aMayusculas(char*, size_t);` pero su uso es más complejo y seguramente no es ni necesario. No veo necesario complicar el código si con la versión básica se cumplen las especificaciones.

Comment: Gracias eferion!

Comment: @P.Matias De nada, para eso estamos.

Comment: Correcto, el codigo es acorde al ejemplo. Ya preguntará porque las cadenas de texto se le sobreescriben, en cuanto que pruebe con un texto de mas de 99 caracteres. Nada que objetar a eso. Tienes mi voto.

Comment: @Trauma Es lo que tiene C... te mueves siempre al filo de la navaja. Si usas funciones seguras tienes que arrastrar más variables de las deseadas... y si vas sin protecciones tienes que estar muy seguro de lo que haces

Comment: @Trauma Además, en este caso las cadenas se procesan después de escribirlas... si se produce _buffer overflow_ no será en mi función sino en la lectura de `gets`

Comment: Cierto es ese último punto, no había caido. Porque los comentarios no tienen puntos, que si no te ponía uno :-) así que tenemos otras 2 preguntas mas pendientes, por que se le sobreescriben y porqué da SIGSEGV, según el tamaño de la cadena que prueba ... ¡ esto es una mina !

Comment: @Trauma Los comentarios si tienen puntos... Si pones el ratón encima de uno verás una flecha gris a la izquierda. No cuentan para puntuación pero si para ciertas medallas. Los comentarios con cierto número de puntos aparecen destacados

Comment: Esto último te lo digo solo para informarte, no es necesario que puntúes el comentario

Comment: Ah, sabia lo de la flechita, pero no el uso. Nada nada, lo prometido es deuda. Ahí lo llevas.